# Any option to make screenshot of lement larger than window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a way to make a screenshot of a div that is larger than the browser window. Changing window dimensions is not an option for many reasons.
I think it could be achieved by making multiple screenshots and joining them, but I don't know how to do it automatically and I've got few thousands of divs to process so I can't make it "by hand".
Also, I've got, from time to time errors of MoveTargetOutOfBoundException, probably because div is not yet loaded but I can handle it with try-catch block. Down is the code I use to move to element.

```
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.moveToElement(element);
            actions.perform();
```

This on the other side is code I've been using to make a screenshot:

```
            File scrn = element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrn, new File("D:\\screens\\p1\\p_" + nmbr + ".png"));
```

To make it clear I've tried both with firefox and chrome drivers and browsers duos and multiple screenshots making methods, with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I used to screen the whole page in Katalon Studio (groovy) using AShot:

```
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies

@Keyword
def capturePageToJpg(String url, String folderPath, Viewport viewport) {
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    String fileName = getEtalonImageFileName(url)
    String filePath = folderPath + fileName
    String toReturn
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(2000)).takeScreenshot(driver)
    BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage()
    int viewportHeight = viewport.getHeight()
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight()
    int pageWidth = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getRect().getWidth()
    if (imageHeight > viewportHeight) {
        image = image.getSubimage(0, 0, pageWidth, imageHeight)
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(filePath))
    File file = new File(filePath)
    if (file.exists()) {
        KeywordUtil.logInfo("Saved file: " + filePath)
        toReturn = filePath
    }
    return toReturn
}
```

`driver.get(url)` was inside `getEtalonImageFileName(url)` method.
`Viewport` object as simple pojo to manage `WebDriver` initial resolution (simulating any viewport):

```
public class Viewport {
    
    String name;
    int width;
    int height;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public Viewport(String name, int width, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

From the image of whole page you can cut subimage of specific `element.getRect()`
See http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Graphics_How_to/Image/Use_the_subImage_Rectangle_method_to_create_the_smaller_image.htm

Comment: Isnt ashot a bit old? Would it works correctly with latest selenium?

Comment: Yes, it is old. I was successfuly using it last year. It was working with all selenium version released in time I was using it. I believe the will be no problem to use it with current version. Let me know in case some trouble.